# Where to save read-only *.db file in android project?

Tags: android, sqlite

Sorry for trivial question, I've a `.db` sqlite3 file that I'm suppose to take data, e.g. it's read-only. But I'm wondering where to import it, while taking the path of this data file in order to connect it? Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific?

Comment: on assets folder if is a pre populated DB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409126/android-pre-populated-database

Answer (score 0):

> import it following path

```
"/data/data/ur_package_name/databases/"
```

Comment: I'm solely aware of 'DRAG AND DROP' :) in eclipse, how to do that programmatically? By the way, *.db is already created!

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have a folder under the project called assets, I put my *.db there and load the database like this:

```
private static void copyDatabase(String dbname) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(dbname);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + dbname;
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        is.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```