# Put database into android project

Tags: android, sqlite

I read about 5 threads already on stackoverflow and still don't know how to do that.
I already have sqlite database and i don't know where to put it in my android studio project.
I want the database download with the application.

Comment: what cannot understand you properly? please put some code and explain your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Pre-Populated Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409126/android-pre-populated-database)

Comment: you want to have a preloaded db ? then you need to put it inside the asset  folder.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't pretend to be the best way, but that is how I made it in my project:
Your database should be in res/assets directory. 
And here is a part of my DataBaseHelper class that might be helpful for you:

```
public class DataBaseHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "yourname.db";

    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    public void openOrCreate() {
        File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        if (!dbFile.exists()) 
            copyDatabase(dbFile);
        mSQLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) {
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            is = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (os != null) os.close();
                if (is != null) is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a preloaded db, then the general approach is 
 1. put the sqlite file in the asset folder.
 2. copy that file to the data directory.

Fortunately, there is a very simple & easy to use Git library [Android Asset Helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Have a look at their usage example.

Comment: @cryuff, instead of writing so many error prone boiler plate coding , this library is generally would be a good decision to use. Rest depends on you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class (.java file) that handles the database for you. That class automatically creates the SQLite database in your android devide. For example, this is a sample code of an android App I`m working on:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 3;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE VISITAS (" +
                   "Id_Visita INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                   ...
                   ");");
    }
...
}
```

Add some more details on what kind of problem or doubt are you having.