# How To Use External Sqlite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am Learning Android I have a Doubt that How To use External SQLite Manager (Add on in Firefox) in android Studio

or

please say How to Use Two TABLE NAMES in Sqlite example :user table and Admin Table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Pre-Populated Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409126/android-pre-populated-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public class SqlLiteDbHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "aa.sqlite";
private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/";

static Context ctx;

public SqlLiteDbHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    ctx = context;
}
public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = getDatabasePath();

    // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
    File f = new File(ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
    if (!f.exists())
        f.mkdir();

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

    }
    // Close the streams

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

private static String getDatabasePath() {

    return ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX + DATABASE_NAME;

}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    File dbFile = ctx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    if (!dbFile.exists()) {
        try {
            CopyDataBaseFromAsset();

            System.out.println("Copying sucess from Assets folder");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);

        }

    }
    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put database with schema like table design and may be data in tables up

to 1 mb in assets folder and when you create instance of sqlite manager then

copy from assets to data/data/packagename/databases/

First Check DAtabase it is already copied or not by using this code

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/packageName/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "dbname.db";

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        if(checkDB.getVersion() < DATABASE_VERSION){
            onUpgrade(checkDB, checkDB.getVersion(), DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

if not exist then

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Open the empty db as the output stream

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```