# How to include a text file for reading and writing?

Tags: android, file, edit

I want to include a file (which contains key-value-pairs) in an android app. I need to have write-access to the file, so I can not put it in `raw` or `assets`.

How can I do this? In standard java, I would just have put it in the project root.

Comment: Include the file in `raw` or `assets`. Then copy it on the storage, *if it's not already there*. Then use the file from the storage. DONE! It's nearly a duplicate of [Shipping an app with a prepopulated database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409126/android-pre-populated-database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to read and write to the internal storage of the device. `getFilesDir()` gives you the file object for your app's private internal storage. And as per the note in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage), if you use `MODE_PRIVATE` with `openFileInput` or `openFileOutput`, the file will be private to your app only.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I include the file with the default values when building the app?

Comment: Keep it in `raw`, copy content from the file in `raw` to file in internal storage. If this works for you, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Well, to me this looks like bad design on androids part. I do not see a problem in just adding a folder to the apk that will automatically extract to the internal storage, thus not making me do that manually. But I guess I will have to deal with it the way it is. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can alternatively download the file from a web server on app's first run and store it in the internal storage.